# SLRequest in IOS 6

Tags: facebook, ios6

How to attach the **UIImage** to the post on Facebook using **SLRequest**. This is my code:

```
SLRequest *facebookRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                                 requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                                      URL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"]
                                                               parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:post forKey:@"message"]];
```

I know that it is necessary to specify the picture in parameters, but I do not know as it to make.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the image as multi-data and with the name "picture".

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
NSData *myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
[facebookRequest addMultipartData:myImageData withName:@"picture" type:@"image/png" filename:nil];
```

Comment: I tried to use your example, but image wasn't attached to the post.

Comment: That's correct. If it answered your question, please accept/close it out.

Comment: Thank you! I had copied/modified this from a working Twitter example I had, and didn't realize I had to change the name from "media" to "picture"...